# Does tf.Dataset.batch by default preload and how to disable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

When `tf.Dataset.batch` is used, `get_next()` will preload some data upon calling. It looks like there is a background thread doing this. Is there is way to disable it?

A reproduction code piece:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def pr(x):
    print(x)
    return x


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10000)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_func(pr, [x], [tf.int64]))

dataset = dataset.batch(3)

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    next_element = iterator.get_next()

    for i in range(2):
        fetches = sess.run(next_element)
        print(fetches)
```

An unstable sample output is like:

```
0
1
2
3
(array([0, 1, 2]),)
4
5
6
(array([3, 4, 5]),)
7
8
```

I would like to have deterministic output as:

```
0
1
2
(array([0, 1, 2]),)
3
4
5
(array([3, 4, 5]),)
```

The environment is OS X+python3.7.2+tensorflow1.13.1 in CPU mode

Comment: The return of your code that I run is the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks for comments. What's your environment? Mine is OS X+python3.7.2+tensorflow1.13.1 + CPU mode as added to the post.

Comment: Ubuntu16.04 + python3.6 + tensorflow1.12+GPU

Comment: Weird. I find a server with same as yours and it prints as expected. Looks like a modification in 1.13.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to the comments with giser_yugang. I found hints from the ChangeLog of 1.13. (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.13.1).

Setting a dataset option fixes this in 1.13

```
import tensorflow as tf

def pr(x):
    print(x)
    return x


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(10000)

options = tf.data.Options()
options.experimental_optimization.apply_default_optimizations = False
dataset = dataset.with_options(options)

dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.py_func(pr, [x], [tf.int64]))

dataset = dataset.batch(3)

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)
    next_element = iterator.get_next()

    for i in range(2):
        fetches = sess.run(next_element)
        print(fetches)
```